# Adding text file to Xcode project and using it in app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I have a .txt file (in plain text format) and I would like to integrate this into a iOS app I am starting to write. The info in the text file must be searchable by the app. Is there a way to do this? If so, what would be best way to do so? Or would I need to add this text file into ViewController.m in code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the txt file to your project and then read it into memory.  Here is one way to read the entire contents into memory at once:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourTextFile" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                              error:&error];

if (error) {
    // handle the error condition
} else {
    // continue your processing
}
```